# why cairo draws curves with dark pixels

Tags: c, 2d, cairo

I try to draw with cairo on iOS. I found very simple example how to [draw rounded rectangle here](https://www.cairographics.org/samples/rounded_rectangle/).

But when I draw white path with this code:

```
int r = 255;
int g = 255;
int b = 255; 

double
    lineWidth   = 6.0,
    degrees     = M_PI / 180.0,
    r           = (double)color.r / 255.0,
    g           = (double)color.g / 255.0,
    b           = (double)color.b / 255.0;

    /* start drawing from half of line width*/
    x      += lineWidth / 2.0;
    y      += lineWidth / 2.0;
    width  -= lineWidth;
    height -= lineWidth;

    cairo_new_sub_path( cr );
    cairo_arc( cr, x + width - radius, y + radius, radius, -90 * degrees, 0 * degrees );
    cairo_arc( cr, x + width - radius, y + height - radius, radius, 0 * degrees, 90 * degrees );
    cairo_arc( cr, x + radius, y + height - radius, radius, 90 * degrees, 180 * degrees );
    cairo_arc( cr, x + radius, y + radius, radius, 180 * degrees, 270 * degrees);
    cairo_close_path( cr );
    cairo_set_fill_rule( cr, CAIRO_FILL_RULE_WINDING );
    cairo_set_source_rgb( cr, r, g, b );
    cairo_fill_preserve( cr );
    cairo_set_source_rgb( cr, r, g, b );
    cairo_set_line_width( cr, lineWidth );
    cairo_stroke( cr );
```

pixels should be white, but on the corner they are not, what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Siggestion, do not write multiple variable definitions in a single statement. As it is your code it would seem that `width` and `height` are of type `double`.

Comment: How are you drawing the blue-ish background? Is that also done with cairo? If not, how else?

Comment: I'm using cocos2dx, but the problem appears just without final drawing. So I just crate image_surface, draw on it and looks to image data, pixels are wrong just after cairo drawing, I use cairo_image_surface_get_data( surface ) to get raw pixels data. Cocos2dx does not affect drawing.